# Old workbook (once opened by VBA) keeps opening when I open another excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am building a database in Access, for which I import data from an Excel workbook questionnaire. I have coded an Import-sub that selects, opens, retrieves the data from and finally closes the workbook.

**The problem is this:** for some reason, when I now open any excel workbook on my computer (at a time when neither Access or Excel is in use) some old version of the questionnaire keeps opening as well. This problem doesn't end by restarting the computer, but only by deleting that specific questionnaire-workbook. But then it starts happening with another workbook.

I have a theory that this might be because I - in my import-sub - have opened the questionnaire, encountered a run-time error which has ended the sub before it closed the workbook, and that somehow the workbook is still "open". Or that there still is a link active.

**So I have two questions:**

**1.)** Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

**2.)** Is there generally any consequences of not closing a workbook that you open through VBA?

My relevant code is:

```
Dim MyXL As Excel.Application
Dim MyWB As Excel.Workbook
...
```

in between lots of stuff happening, several times an error occurs which interrupts the program.

```
...
MyWB.Close False
MyXL.Quit
```

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Or maybe you have some code in the Personal.xlsb file?

Comment: Open Excel, Go to VBA Editor and on the Left Hand Side, do you see the Personal file? If yes, then open the `ThisWorkbook` and see if you have any code there?

Comment: No, there is no code under "This workbook" for the specific file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your theory is likely. If you never display the Excel application, errors are encountered, and your code never closes the workbook it would be left open in the background and your code would most likely lose reference to it. The next time you open an Excel file the instance of Excel that is already open(but hidden from view) "picks up" the request and opens the file, also displaying the file that was still open from the macro.

**1.)** You should set up error handling so that the Workbook and Excel application are closed when there is a non-recoverable error.

```
Sub MySub()
    On Error GoTo handle_Err

    <... code ...>

    Exit Sub
handle_Err:
    MyWB.Close False
    MyXL.Quit
End Sub
```

If you have other Error handling statements in your code always reset to `On Error GoTo handle_Err` instead of `GoTo 0` etc.

**2.)** The only consequences of not closing the Workbook are the obvious ones- the system resources it's using and, if it is open for editing, no one else can edit it.

Comment: I have actually implemented error handling mid-way through my project, so probably the problem that opens the workbook has occurred before then. But there is one thing with error handling that I don't get that might play into the problem I am having: 1) Let say i am still developing the code, and that I want to get the window generated by the "on error goto 0" (default) for immediate debugging, then that would interupt the closing of the document as well right? Can I somehow send it back to where the error occured after using "on error goto errorhandler"?

Comment: 2) Secondly, if I am exiting the sub at some point (lets say because the user don't want to overwrite existing data), then I have an IF-statement with an "exit sub" in it. However, this way, the code never gets to the closing-the-workbook-code at the end. I have seen such exiting be done in similar projects, but I am unsure whether or not I should include the closing-statement before every exit-statement throughout the sub? Thank you very much for your help btw Ross!

Comment: Concerning your first comment, putting `MyWB.Close False` and `MyXL.Quit` in the immediate window, while debugging will do the trick. Also, in the task manager's processes tab you can also see your hidden instances of excel and focibly close them as a last resort. Concerning the second comment, yeah, you should, if you want to close and quit the excel application.

Comment: 1) Yes, the `Resume` keyword is used to resume execution on the next line after an Error was encountered. 2) All points of exit in the subroutine should `GoTo` your handler label that closes the Workbook. This is the correct way to handle any kind of open files or objects that access external data that are specific to subroutine's scope- when an error is thrown, close them all out before exiting the subroutine.

Comment: If you've been prompted with the End/Debug window, gone into Debug mode, and have corrected an error in the coding you can hit F5 or press the play button to resume execution. You can also click and drag the yellow arrow next to the highlighted row where the error was encountered and move it to change where execution resumes at when you press play or F5.

Answer (score 1):

I did Encounter the same Problem and found out that Excel stores the files that open whenever you start Excel in a Folder (XLSTART). The path to mine was: `c:\USERS\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`

As suggested by Ross McConeghy error handling may prevent such an occurrence. But the error already happened and the questionnaire, as you suggested, has placed that workbook in the Folder XLSTART. You have to delete it from that folder to fix the unwanted occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it a different way.
I found the connection to an external workbook and fixed it by going to Data > Edit Links.